# Spring Authorization Server, Spring Gateway & OAuth Client setup in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I have a microservice that contains from modules:

- spring-config-server (spring-cloud-config-server);
- spring-eureka-server (spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server);
- spring-authorization-server (spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server);
- spring-gateway (spring-cloud-starter-gateway, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client);
- spring-resource-server (spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server);
- client (spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf, React app prod build);

I want to work with it in Kubernetes. I am using Minikube for local development.
I have started Microservice in Kubernetes since few days ago. I have opened access to gateway using command
`kubectl port-forward service/spring-cloud-gateway 8090:8090`
[default page at http://localhost:8090/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe8xi.png)
I have a problem with Authentication. When I was trying to log in I got an error. Error caused by redirect to OAuth server by URL http://spring-authorization-server:9000/oauth2/authorize [visual explanation on the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IX9k.png)
that is spring:security:oauth2:client:provider:spring:issuer-uri: http://spring-authorization-server:9000, but spring-gateway with this configuration that is also oauth2 client starts successfully when it send starting requests to spring authorization server using it's internal WebClient.
I have solved this problem for docker-compose environment by adding to /etc/hosts following lines:

```
127.0.0.1 spring-cloud-gateway
127.0.0.1 spring-authorization-server
```

and it does not work with Kubernetes

I have no skill how to solve it now. Maybe Ingress configuration can help here, but I am not sure about it and how to setup Ingress, for example, NGINX Ingress I also do not know. I have tried to chat with ChatGPT and it genered config file for me, but it does not help

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: spring-cloud-gateway.local
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: spring-cloud-gateway
                port:
                  number: 8090
    - host: spring-authorization-server.local
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: spring-authorization-server
                port:
                  number: 9000
```

ChatGPT also proposed to add to /etc/hosts
`${minikube ip} spring-cloud-gateway.local`
I added it and it does not help, maybe because I can't to get an access to gateway service using `http://${minikube ip}:8090` in the browser and I need to do something with this.